# Calling text file

Tags: matlab, floating-accuracy

if i have text file that has three column say

```
                                           1 2 1
                                           3 1 1
                                           2 3 1
```

and also have a matrix s =

```
                    [0.3  0.4   0.6
                     0.1  0.5  0.7
                     0.2  0.11  0.9]
```

firstly:
with respect to text file, i want to consider first column as i and second column as j then if the third column equal 1 then put its corresponding value in matrix s in new array say A else put remaining value in matrix s in new another array say B.

i.e  i want this result

A=[0.4,  0.2,   0.7]    B=[0.3,  0.6,  0.1,  0.5, 0.11,  0.9]

Comment: Please share a copy of your working code.

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried? This question won't get any more attention until you pinpoint which programming language you want.

Comment: i want this code in matlab

Answer (score 0):

```
coordinates = [1 2 1
               3 1 1
               2 3 1];
s =  [0.3  0.4   0.6
      0.1  0.5   0.7
      0.2  0.11  0.9];

linindices = sub2ind(size(s), coordinates(:, 1), coordinates(:, 2))';

A = s(linindices)

B = s(setdiff(1:numel(s), linindices))
```